# UI Control for presenting data base in the iphone and Android applications

Tags: android, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm developing an application for CRM proposes. In this application I need to present data of data bases with about 8-9 columns.

Is there any ui control for presenting data bases in the mobile applications at all? I know that list view(on the android) and table view (on the iphone) can used for this propose but I believe that this controls do not created for this proposes.

So as mobile devices have small screens what solution or what controls we have for presenting databases in the mobile devices?